# How to spray paint face-down surfaces?

Tags: painting, spraying, spraypainting

I'm watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnIZ_wABrJU) video on how to spray paint metal, and it's pretty good.

One thing I don't get though, is how to paint the surfaces that the objects are resting on? Do you simply have to wait for the paint to dry and then change the orientation of the piece to apply paint to the other sides? This seems like it would cause the paint to become uneven.

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Painting all but the bottom side first is a valid approach.

However, I usually hang whatever I'm painting in such a way that I can paint all surfaces at the same time, especially if I need a continuous finish.

Comment: Coat hangers, clipped with a wire cutter so as to create a hook, hang nicely from overhead water pipes and such.